# É possível obter resultados multivalorados num group by?

Tags: banco-de-dados

Tenho 3 tabelas no banco: Professor, Aluno e Disciplina. Todas elas possuem relacionamentos de N:M entre si. Então decidir reunir todos os relacionamentos numa única tabela turma, que armazena a chave estrangeira das 3 tabelas.

Para montar a página preciso retornar do banco algo parecido com essa estrutura:

> object(Turma)[6] 
>   -- private 'turma' => string 'Bancos A239812' (length=15) 
>   -- private 'dtIni' => string '2012-01-20' (length=10)
>   -- private 'dtFim' => string '2012-06-20' (length=10)
>   -- private 'turno' => string 'matutino' (length=8)
>   -- private 'n1' => string '' (length=0)
>   -- private 'n2' => string '' (length=0)
>   -- private 'n3' => string '' (length=0)
>   -- private 'professor' => string 'Bruno Faria' (length=11) 
>   -- private 'aluno' => 
>     ---- array (size=2)
>     ------  0 => 
>     --------- 'nome' => string 'Amanda dos Santos' (length=17)
>     ------ 1 => 
>     --------  'nome' => string 'Nalva de Souza Sá' (length=18)
>   -- private 'disciplina' => string 'Banco de Dados II' (length=17)

Para obter esse resultado eu consigo fazer com duas buscas:

```
SELECT t.turma AS turma, p.nome AS professor, d.nome AS disciplina, t.dt_ini AS dtIni, t.dt_fim AS dtFim, t.turno AS turno  
FROM turma AS t 
INNER JOIN professor AS p 
INNER JOIN disciplina AS d 
ON t.turma COLLATE utf8_general_ci = busca_banco AND p.id = t.pk_professor AND  d.id = t.pk_disciplina 
GROUP BY t.turma

SELECT a.nome 
FROM turma AS t 
INNER JOIN aluno AS a 
ON t.pk_aluno = a.id AND t.turma COLLATE utf8_general_ci = turma AND t.dt_ini = data_ini AND t.dt_fim = data_Fim 
ORDER BY a.nome
```

**Gostaria de saber se é possível fazer em uma única query. Essa query deve fazer uma busca pelo nome da turma e agrupar os resultados (GROUP BY).**

**Porém na mesma query eu quero retornar o nome de todos os alunos que estão cursando a disciplina.**

**Então tenho um agrupamento, mas gostaria de obter várias tuplas pra um dos campos. Isso é possível?**

Comment: Qual banco de daos?

Comment: mysql...........

Comment: tentou usar um union?

Comment: > Não deu certo: _Cardinality violation: 1222 The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns_

Answer (score 0):

Visto que a quantidade e os tipos dos campos das duas querys são diferentes, você não tem como fazer uma única pesquisa, nem mesmo com o UNION. A melhor forma de você juntar estes dados é fazer um query para o nome dos alunos da turma e outra para retornar os demais itens. Como segue:

Query 1

```
SELECT 
    t.turma AS turma,
    p.nome AS professor,
    d.nome AS disciplina,
    t.dt_ini AS dtIni,
    t.dt_fim AS dtFim,
    t.turno AS turno
FROM
    turma AS t
        INNER JOIN
    professor AS p
        INNER JOIN
    disciplina AS d ON t.turma COLLATE utf8_general_ci = busca_banco
        AND p.id = t.pk_professor
        AND d.id = t.pk_disciplina
GROUP BY t.turma
```

Query 2

```
SELECT 
    a.nome
FROM
    turma AS t
        INNER JOIN
    aluno AS a ON t.pk_aluno = a.id
        AND t.turma COLLATE utf8_general_ci = turma
        AND t.dt_ini = data_ini
        AND t.dt_fim = data_Fim
ORDER BY a.nome
```